# Why is "dict_views" not assignable or printable as a type?

Tags: python-3.x

What is different about `dict_views`, that I can't just assign it or print it as a type?

**So, that works:**

```
print(type({1:1}.keys())
<class dict_keys>
```

**That doesn't:**

```
print(dict_keys) 
>NameError: name 'dict_keys' is not defined
```

As some people think, that i expect `dict_keys` to be a variable, I've already stated in the title, that I'm trying to access the `type dict_views` not a variable`dict_views`

Comment: Because `dict_keys` isn't a name in your scope. It's also a special C-type object in the CPython implementation - so you can't (and aren't supposed to) do anything with it at the Python level except its exposed methods.

Comment: That's not what that code prints.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed it, missing the `name` is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to do

```
>>> print(dict_keys)
```

That attempts a variable lookup for a `dict_keys` variable. There is no `dict_keys` variable. The lookup fails.

---

The name you see in

```
>>> type({}.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

has **nothing to do with** variable lookup. That's the class's `__name__` attribute. The `__name__` can be whatever the writer of the class wants it to be. For classes like `int` or `collections.OrderedDict`, the `__name__` is usually set to match the name of the variable the class is available through, but that's not required, and there's no requirement that the class be available through any variable at all.

Comment: so why can i do `print(int)`?

Comment: Because there's an `int` variable referring to the int class.